how can i delete a page?
I created a page and decided to replace it with another, so I deleted it, then I realized that even though I deleted it, it still appears in the navigation menu.
and if I click on the page it redirects me to a page that doesn't exist so I get an error
(https://i.sstatic.net/oJlYDtmA.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/CbYKS4xr.png)
i deleted the page expecting it would disappear from the navigation bar

If you mean, the deleted page's navigation menu item is still shown on the menu, delete also its navigation menu entry by:
Shared components -> navigation menu -> delete entry

Did you delete it with file explorer while keeping the editor open? If so, closing and reopening the editor should solve the problem.

I think you misunderstood the question. In Oracle Apex we don't use "editor" nor "file explorer". What exactly are you talking about?
